# Custom Columns in Serilog SqLite

Tags: database, sqlite, logging, serilog

Im currently writing to a SQLite db file using Serilog.Sinks.SqLite. This works fine however i would like to create custom columns in this db file. I have managed to Enrich the properties column with various enrichers (ProcessName, EnviromentName etc) but i need to conform to a specific column format.

I cant find any worthwhile documentation on this package. How would one go about creating these custom columns?

Alternative solution:
How can i configure the (much beter documented) MSSQL sink to write to an SQLite file?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit late but I'll give my answer.

You can download the source code of `Serilog.Sinks.SqLite` from [github](https://github.com/saleem-mirza/serilog-sinks-sqlite/blob/dev/src/Serilog.Sinks.SQLite/Sinks/SQLite/SQLiteSink.cs).
In your solution, after removing the reference of `Serilog.Sinks.SQLite` dll you have, you can add the reference to the downloaded project.

In the new source code you can access the `SQLiteSink.cs` file and modify the following method per your needs:

- `CreateTable`: you can define your columns
- `CreateSqlInsertCommand`: set the INSERT command following the table definition
- `WriteToDatabaseAsync`: define the parameter values for your INSERT command